# why i am getting an error of incorrect integer value on age? while i am using the correct data type and values in it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
insert into  `patient` ( `pat_f_name`, `pat_l_name`, `pat_gender`, `pat_age`, `pat_dob`, `pat_blood_grp`, `pat_weight`, `pat_contact_no`, `pat_address` )
    ->  VALUES
    ->  ('$user_fname','$user_lname','$user_gender','$user_age','$user_dob','$user_bg','$user_weight','$user_contact_no','$user_address');
```

> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '$user_age' for column 'pat_age' at row 1

the table looks like

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pat_id         | int(50)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| dr_id          | int(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pat_f_name     | char(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pat_l_name     | char(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pat_gender     | char(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pat_age        | int(20)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pat_dob        | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pat_blood_grp  | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pat_weight     | int(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pat_contact_no | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pat_address    | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Seems like you want to get rid of the quotes around the php variables

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO patient(pat_f_name, pat_l_name, pat_gender, pat_age, pat_dob, pat_blood_grp, pat_weight, pat_contact_no, pat_address) VALUES ('$user_fname','$user_lname','$user_gender','$user_age','$user_dob','$user_bg','$user_weight','$user_contact_no','$user_address')";
```

Comment: $query ="insert into  `patient` (pat_f_name, pat_l_name, pat_gender, pat_age, pat_dob, pat_blood_grp, pat_weight, pat_contact_no, pat_address)
 VALUES
 ('$user_fname','$user_lname','$user_gender','$user_age','$user_dob','$user_bg','$user_weight','$user_contact_no','$user_address')";

Comment: but still it's not taking the value

Comment: echo the $sql and paste the output here.

Comment: it is not giving me any error on localhost and nor putting my value in DB.. but when i write code on SQL then it gives me bundle of erroes

Comment: ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '$user_age' for column 'pat_age' at row 1

Comment: please echo the $sql and paste the output here

Comment: i am new to programming so i have no idea how to echo this ?

Comment: Simply echo $sql; die; after your query

Comment: echo $query ="insert into  `patient` "like this"??

Comment: No below this line do this

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO patient(pat_f_name, pat_l_name, pat_gender, pat_age, pat_dob, pat_blood_grp, pat_weight, pat_contact_no, pat_address) VALUES ('$user_fname','$user_lname','$user_gender','$user_age','$user_dob','$user_bg','$user_weight','$user_contact_no','$user_address')";

echo $sql; die; submit your form first

Comment: i have defined this...??

Comment: INSERT INTO patient(pat_f_name, pat_l_name, pat_gender, pat_age, pat_dob, pat_blood_grp, pat_weight, pat_contact_no, pat_address) VALUES ('Sadaf','Ahmed','female','20','','A−','‌​50','','')

Comment: its not taking address and contact no ??

Comment: Now copy this query and run in PHPMyAdmin and let me know about the error.

Comment: #1366 - Incorrect integer value: '$user_age' for column 'pat_age' at row 1